# Button press to add and remove elements from array LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am trying to make an upgradable array of elements in LabVIEW that the contented will be pushed in with a button press
I have created the input to the shift register as a typedef of the control cluster

[image]

[image]

On top of that I would like to add the ability to remove elements from the array based on selection

E.g. to have a check box that I can select elements in the array and when pressing remove thy will be deleted and the array will be refreshed or updated.

I am not sure how to add the selection box and remove button from the array

Should I convert the array to a list or something?
Where do i add the selection checkbox  (is it to the cluster type def?)

I have tried the following but facing 2 issues:

1. I can't toggle the checkbox button on the array
2. When pressing delete it deletes the full array

[image]

Appreciate the help
Assaf Baker

Comment: Are you sure you want the Stop button to do the same thing as the Add button (except close the loop)?

Comment: I built exactly this in the dialog boxes included in this LV right-click plugin. https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-Shortcut-Menu-Plug-Ins/Edit-A-Set-Value-llb-Edit-A-Map-Value-llb/ta-p/4020190?profile.language=en

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest, but user-friendly solution would be to:

- add checkbox to the cluster
- add button "Delete"
- add event case "Delete: Value Changed"
- in the event case iterate through all "Array 2" elements using "for" loop
- if the iterated element has checkbox selected, delete it using "Delete from array" function

Comment: i have added to the original post based upon suggestions cant add a replay

Comment: you're right, I forgot that the array in your code is an indicator (output), not a control (input)

Comment: Do you know local variables? You can change array to be a control, disable it's string and numeric fields and use local variable to update the array value in the loop, but I'm not sure if it makes sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, but in this case, I am entirely unsure how to answer your question in anything short of a full example, which is many VIs long.

The dialogs used in this right-click plugin do exactly what you are trying to do. Download [the .zip file on this page](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-Shortcut-Menu-Plug-Ins/Edit-A-Set-Value-llb-Edit-A-Map-Value-llb/ta-p/4020190) and place the two LLBs inside in the directory:

```
<labview data>\PopupMenus\edit time panel and diagram
```

Then launch LabVIEW and drop either a set control on a front panel. Right click and choose "Data Operations >> Edit Value...". The dialog that appears has the ability to add and remove elements just as you are requesting.

The VI that you want to inspect is:

```
<LabVIEW Data>\PopupMenus\edit time panel and diagram\Edit A Set Value.llb\Dialog.vi
```

[image: editing a set]

Answer (score 0):

With a basic state machine (while loop - case structue or event) to build a FGV (Fuctional Global Varible).

Avoid mix of events, you will need for example these events:

- Timeout 100ms to update controls and user response.
- Add buttons to push cluster to array
- Del buttons to remove from array the select box or bolean selector
- Array event to update shift register or contect in local variables
- Stop

Well I still can't add image, for delete you can use a for loop with tunnel mode in coditional.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrTED.png)